# MariaDB GRANT command fails with syntax error

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I'm trying to execute:

```
GRANT SYSTEM VARIABLES ADMIN on *.* TO thomas;
```

on `MariaDB 10.5`, but it fails with:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARIABLES ADMIN
ON *.* to thomas' at line 1

Looking at the docs seems to validate it looks correct:
https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql-dbaas/ref/xpand/privileges/SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN/

Testing on local MariaDB and remote cloud hosted.

Comment: this would only work on skysql, not in an "normal" Mariadb installation

Comment: How do you do it on a normal MariaDB?

Comment: [various ADMIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/) grants exist all of which control some global system variables, however unlike SkySQL there is no `SYSTEM VARIABLES` grant available.